# Replacing /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: filesystem, internet, dns

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1. But in no way could I make the Internet work. I messed up trying to replace the /etc/resolv.conf file and it got removed... I would like to download it using the cd boot and put it where it should be. Problem is, I have no idea how to download and where to put it.

(I'm quite a newbie, easy steps plz) thank you :)

Comment: Run `sudo service resolvconf restart` and then check....

Comment: I think it fixed itself when I was restarting the computer (switching systems). Is that possible? Looks ok now... Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: Please check my answer..explanation given..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is auto generated by `resolvconf` program in Ubuntu. The first line of the file contains:

```
Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
```

It is actually a symbolic link to `/var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Feb  9 22:23 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

So, in a nutshell if you just restart the `resolvconf` service by the following command `/etc/resolv.conf` will be auto generated again:

```
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

Actually you don't need to restart the computer.

Comment: I typed the command 'Sudo service resolvconf restart' the output is 'resolconf: unrecognized service' sooo.. I guess it's not just the file. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: @Olalike: You typed `resolconf` hence the error `resolconf: unrecognized service`.. type exactly: `sudo service resolvconf restart`

Comment: Hmm no I didn't it was just a comment typo. (Sorry)

Comment: @Olalike: no problem..please select the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left side of my answer so that this issue can be marked as resolved.

Comment: Was going too. Thx